# Use regex extract several info

Tags: java, regex

How can I extract several information from a sentence by regex? I want to extract the number and the Name from a phrase.

For example,

```
buy a $30 giftcard for John
buy John a $30 giftcard
```

I expect the output is "30" and "John"

Comment: Are those sentence patterns fixed? What if the sentence is “_buy $30 giftcards, 5 for John and 2 for Jane_”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression,

```
\$(\d+)|(\b[A-Z]\S+\b)
```

for instance extract those outputs.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\$(\\d+)|(\\b[A-Z]\\S+\\b)";
final String string = "buy a $30 giftcard for John\n"
     + "buy John a $30 giftcard";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### Demo

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/R4u3mr/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks, that is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. It also allows expansion with additional patterns in the `Pattern` array.  As long as your patterns are unique, you can match on multiple items without having to specify all permutations of the patterns.

```java
      String amount = "\\$(\\d+)";
      String name = "(\\b[A-Z][a-z]+\\b)";
      Pattern[] patterns = { Pattern.compile(amount), Pattern.compile(name)
      };
      String[] testStrings =
            { "buy a $30 giftcard for John", "buy John a $30 giftcard"
            };

      for (String test : testStrings) {
         for (Pattern pat : patterns) {
            Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(test);
            if (matcher.find()) {
               System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
            }
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
```